# Initializing static variable for each request

Tags: java, xml, rest

Here is the scenario, when I receive a rest request, I have to do some xml transformation and in order to build some of the xml elements I am triggering a java code that build that for me. For example,

```
<Parent>
   <element A>
   // This is created using java code, this is an array element
   <ComplexElement B>
       <element 1>
       <element 2>
   </ComplexElement B> 
</Parent>
```

so that java code is triggered multiple times in the same request as I have array in the request, so I have to iterate it and that is why the java code is triggered for each iteration of the array.

In the java code I am maintaining a static list, so when the java code is triggered and if it is for the first time in the iteration, it adds the element ID to the list, so that if the element is repeated, I can lookup in the list and create it only one time instead of repeating it. However the issue I am running into is that the list being static is not garbage collected and is being carried over to the next request. So even though the next request is a new request, there is a chance that the element creation might be skipped if the previous request has already added the element id in the list.

Is there a better way to handle this or a simpler way to maintain a list only for that request. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I probably wouldn't use `static` for this purpose. Instantiate a new list on each request, and pass that where it is needed.

Comment: why don't you clear it at the end of the loop.

Comment: That is not valid xml.